# How to add a passphrase for ssh key after its been created?

Tags: github

Is generating a new one necessary, or is there a way to go back and add a passphrase?
I have generated an ssh key, but would like to go back and add a passphrase. I haven't linked it to my github yet. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [explained here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/119327), you can add a passphrase to an existing private key with:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -o -p -f keyfile
```

But you can also link that to GitHub immediately: adding a passphrase (encrypting the private key) does not change the *public* key you would register to your GitHub profile.
The public key will remain the same, before and after you add a passphrase to your local private key.